# PythonQt how to override virtual function

Tags: function, overriding, virtual, wrapper, python-c-api

I am trying to add Python scripting capability to my Qt application. So far, I have been able to write wrappers for many classes. However, one class has a virtual 'init()' function which can be overridden by a derived class if necessary.

```
// C++ class 
class MyClass : public QObject
{
 Q_OBJECT
 public:
  MyClass() 
  {
   init(); // perform user initialization
  }
  virtual void init() {}
};
```

The MyClass constructor calls the virtual function 'init()'. It is intended that when MyClass is sub-classed that the init function can be overridden if necessary to provide user initialization.

I wish to use 'MyClass' in PythonQt so I have written a wrapper class:

```
class MyClass_Wrapper : public QObject
{
 Q_OBJECT
public Q_SLOTS:
 // add a constructor
 MyClass* new_MyClass() {return new MyClass(); }
 void init(MyClass* mc) { mc->init(); }
};
```

The class 'MyClass' is now registered with PythonQt:

```
    PythonQt::self()->registerCPPClass("MyClass",NULL,"myModule", PythonQtCreateObject<MyClass_Wrapper>);
```

Now, I create a Python script to use 'MyClass':

```
import myModule
Class TestClass(MyClass) :
  def init(self):
  # init() is called exactly once at the beginning to do
  # any necessary configuration.
  print "Inside init(self)"
  .
  .
  .
  return
```

The problem is that the print statement (and the following code) is never executing. The init() function is not being overridden by the PythonQt code.

Comment: The solution is to use the PythonQt gerator app to create the wrappers. There is more on this here: https://sourceforge.net/p/pythonqt/discussion/631392/thread/2ac02fc5/?limit=25